# Defenition of a function and integrability exercise doubt

Tags: measure-theory

I am having trouble understanding the point of the following exercise and the meaning of its solution:
[image]

[image]

I have some serious doubts about this exercise:

**(1)** What is intended to be real-valued function? Is it $\mathscr{F}$-measurable function if we consider $\mathscr{F}$ to be a $\sigma-\text{field}$?

**(2)** What does it mean $f_2-f_1$ to be defined a.e on $D$? $f_2$ is already assumed to have domain on $D$.

**(3)** Is $f_2$ proved to be measurable and inferable on $D$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For (2), it could be possible that $f_{2}(x)=f_{1}(x)=\infty$ for some point $x$ in $D$, in which case $f_{2}(x)-f_{1}(x)$ is not defined. For (3), $f_{2}$ is measurable by assumption, but it need not be integrable.

Comment: @user363464 (2) the solution claims $f_2(x)-f_1(x)$ to be defined. How is this possible given your last statement?

Comment: Because $f_{1}$ is integrable, $f_{1}(x)=\infty$ only on a set of measure zero, so outside a set of measure zero, $f_{2}-f_{1}$ is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an example will help to understand where you have to be carefull. Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $D=\mathbb{R}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$. Define $f_1,f_2:\mathbb{R}\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ with $f_1(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k}\chi_{[0,1/k]}(x)$ where $\chi_{[a,b]}$ is the characteristic function on $[a,b]$. Futher define $f_2=\infty\chi_{[-1,0]}$.

Then $f_1$ is nonnegative and integrable with $\int f_1=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k}\int\chi_{[0,1/k]}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k^2}<\infty$, while $f_2$ is nonnegative and measureable but not integrable with $\int f_2 = \infty\int\chi_{[-1,0]}=\infty$.

**(1)** $f_1$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, so $f_1$ is a.e. real valued. In this example you can directly see that $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}~:~f_1(x)=\infty\}=\{0\}$ and $f_1$ is real valued on $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$. Since $\mu(A)=0$ you get, that $f_1$ is real valued a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$.

**(2)** Since $f_1(0)=\infty=f_2(0)$ your difference $f_2-f_1$ is not defined for $x=0$. But if $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus A$, then $f_1$ is real valued and $f_2-f_1$ is defined. Therefore $f_2-f_1$ is defined a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$ (but not on whole $\mathbb{R}$!)

**(3)** Neither $f_2$ nor $f_2-f_1$ is integrable, but the equation still holds with $\infty=\infty$.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you!